# meaning of "work for it"

Tags: meaning

*We need to learn, or re-learn, how to build comradeship and solidarity instead of doing capital’s **work for it** by condemning and abusing each other*

Source: https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/opendemocracyuk/exiting-vampire-castle/

I‘m not sure to which part is "it" connected to in the sentence above. Or does the phrase "work for it" speak for itself?

Comment: 'it' is 'capital'.

Comment: "Capital" is being "personified" here (as some kind of malign entity that either doesn't care about comradeship and solidarity, or is actively *hostile* to such things). The idea is that capital[ism] *wants to* or *must* do certain things (boost company profits, reduce workers to slavery, make people abuse each other, whatever) - supposedly, that's the "work" of capitalism, and people who seek different goals shouldn't assist capitalism's efforts to encourage such behaviour.